Reference for Faltings' proof on finiteness of semisimple $d$-dimensional $p$-adic Galois representations
I'm looking for a reference to Faltings' proof concerning the finiteness of $d$-dimensional semisimple $p$-adic Galois representations. Specifically, the result states that there are only finitely many such representations (up to isoms) that are unramified outside a fixed set of primes $S$ and are pure of a fixed weight.
I've seen this result mentioned in various contexts, but I haven't been able to track down the original reference or a detailed proof. Could someone point me to a comprehensive source that covers this proof in detail, or provide some intuition on how to approach this statement so I could fill in the missing details.
Thank you in advance for your help!

The reference is  "Rational Points"
Seminar Bonn/Wuppertal 1983/84 by Faltings, Wüstholz et al, Viehweg 1986. The theorem there states that for a number field $K$, a finite set of places $S$ and given integers $n\geq 1$ and $w\geq 0$, the set of isomorphism classes of $\ell$-adic representations of $K$ that are semisimple and integral of degree $n$ and weight $w$ and unramified outside $S$ is finite. The gist of the proof is to define an equivalence relation between such representations when their corresponding $L$-functions are equal

The reference is  "Rational Points"
Seminar Bonn/Wuppertal 1983/84 by Faltings, Wüstholz et al, Viehweg 1986. The theorem there states that for a number field $K$, a finite set of places $S$ and given integers $n\geq 1$ and $w\geq 0$, the set of isomorphism classes of $\ell$-adic representations of $K$ that are semisimple and integral of degree $n$ and weight $w$ and unramified outside $S$ is finite. The gist of the proof is to define an equivalence relation between such representations when their corresponding $L$-functions are equal and observe that there are only a finite number of equivalence relations because there are only a finite number of their Euler factors. Next, they show that equivalent representations are isomorphic using that there exists a finite set of places $T$ disjoint with $S$ such that if the traces of the Frobenius for places in $T$ are equal, then the representations are isomorphic. I don't have the book with me now to give you the exact pages where these results are proved, but it is certainly easy to find these results there. Thanks to @coLaideronnette
for the exact pages in the reference. I just recalled that there is another version of the proof, by Deligne, in the "Séminaire sur les pinceaux arithmétiques: La conjecture de Mordell" by L. Szpiro et al,  Astérisque, 127, 1987, Exposé IX, page 249.

The proof starts from page 161, in section 2.4 of Wüstholz‘s chapter ‘THE FINITENESS THEOREMS OF FALTINGS’.
